# Which subclause of C++ standard prohibits redeclaration / redefinition in a same block?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm reading [Standard for Programming Language C++](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868) and I cannot find a subclause prohibiting code like follows, which will obviously not compile:

```
/* Code A */
int main() {
  int i;
  int i;
}
```

while this one will compile:

```cpp
/* Code B */
int main() {
  int i;
  { int i; }
}
```

I've found something related, but I failed to find a matching one:

> [[basic.def.odr#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#1)]: No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable...

If it's this subclause, I cannot find a subclause explaining why the 2 `i`'s are not the same variable in Code B but are the same variable in Code A;

> [[basic.scope.block#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.scope.block#1)]:A name declared in a block ([stmt.block]) is local to that block; it has block scope. Its potential scope begins at its point of declaration ([basic.scope.pdecl]) and ends at the end of its block. A variable declared at block scope is a local variable.

In fact I tried to look for something like or more general than "A name of variable with a block scope cannot be redeclared within its potential scope, excluding nested blocks" like [[temp.local#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.local#6)], but I failed:

> [[temp.local#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.local#6)]: The name of a template-parameter shall not be redeclared within its scope (including nested scopes). ...

So can some give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.scope.declarative#4.1, except that I'm not sure that analog of https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.scope#2.2 existed prior to P1787

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [[basic.scope.scope]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.scope#5)

> Two declarations *potentially conflict* if they correspond and cause their shared name to denote different entities ([basic.link]). **The program is ill-formed if, in any scope, a name is bound to two declarations that potentially conflict and one precedes the other ([basic.lookup]).**

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: emm, it says "No two declarations (re)introduce **the same entity**", it's same to my first question about "[basic.def.odr#1]: No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable..." that Why the two `i`'s are introducing a same entity? If it says "No two declarations using the same name in a same scope" then it can solve my question (as the definition of scope seems to have changed in this version)

Comment: Maybe "No two declarations using the same name in a same scope" should be "No two declarations using the same name with a same immediate scope"

Comment: @XuanInsr In your first code block you declare twice the variable `main()::i`.  A variable is an entity and with the above rule you are not allowed to do that.  In your second block of code you declare `main()::i` and `main()::sub_scope::i`, those are two different variable and thus two different entities so the code is valid.

Comment: Oh I think I found it! [[basic.scope.scope#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.scope.scope#5)]: Two declarations potentially conflict if they correspond and cause their shared name to denote different entities ([basic.link]). The program is ill-formed if, in any scope, a name is bound to two declarations that potentially conflict and one precedes the other ([basic.lookup]). So if the 2 declarations introduce different entities, then according to this subclause, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: _A variable is an entity and with the above rule you are not allowed to do that_ With the above rule, 2 `int i;` just introduce 2 different variables, unless otherwise specified

Comment: @XuanInsr yes, /5 is the right paragraph

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Not sure how I read pargraph 2 wrong but I've updated the answer to point to paragraph 5.

Comment: _Not sure how I read pargraph 2 wrong_ It does not say «shall» or «shall not», it doesn't allow or prohibit anything

Comment: Also, note the author is referring to pre-P1787 wording in their question.

Comment: /2 just says: if you see 2 different declarations `D1` and `D2`, they, by default, declare 2 different entities (assuming they declare entities)